# Which is more useful to the mods, Flagging comments, or the Q or A they are in?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

There have been recent events where a good deal of unhelpful comments have hit some Questions and Answers. In most cases they all come in a series of them.

Would it be more useful to the mods for us to *flag the individual comments*, or just *flag the question/answer itself* and note that it's collecting unhelpful or rude comments?

Comment: Perhaps insert a comment politely asking the users to move along? That's what I do, doesn't always work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is bascially the same as the one [I gave](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4488/325) on [How to report multiple obsolete comments?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/how-to-report-multiple-obsolete-comments), with one exception (and why I'm answering instead of closing as a dupe):

If, among a big pile of comments that need to be handled, individual comments are **unambiguously rude** -- I mean things like name-calling, slurs, that kind of thing -- then go ahead and flag those individually too.

Even if we can't get to the whole thread right away, it's worth calling out stuff that needs to go away Right Now.  But please don't do that for cases where it's only clear that it's an insult because of the context from these other 7 comments or something you have to know about the people involved etc -- the point of calling them out is so that a busy moderator can make a snap judgment.

If we can't tell just by looking at that one comment, it'll wait until we can dig into the context.  And at that point it's easier to just flag the post -- easier for you and easier for mods.

Comment: Good advice.  I was thinking more of a stream of obviously rude ones as opposed to inferred insult

Comment: Yep. It's worth noting that if a comment is bad enough, there are keywords that allow flags to auto delete it without mod intervention and I believe that if enough rude/abusive flags hit it an autodelete happens.